# Unable to Call Method from Business Layer

Tags: .net

I am working on a project that has three layers: business, data, and presentation.

The business layer contains table adapters which interact with a SQL database.

I wrote a new method to interact with a SQL database in the business layer, but when I try to reference it outside in the presentation layer, it cannot be found.

Comment: Have you added a reference to your business layer within your presentation layer?  (right click on project -> add reference)

Comment: are the different layers in different projects? different solutions? different namespaces?

Comment: This isn't enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the work space and recreating it from scratch and then performed a rebuild/clean and it now properly references. I also switched from Visual Studio 2012 to 2013-- though I'm not sure if that made a difference. I also made sure to add the Business layer as a reference to the Presentation layer.

Hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the method declared is public and that it is part of the interface if you are deriving from one. Other than that, there isn't any code examples or information on your project, so we can't help you any further.